# Struts2: Get id from request prior to getModel() call

Tags: struts2, model-driven

I encountered the problem after upgrading Struts2 to 2.3.15 from 2.3.1
In my action I use ModelDriven Interface to populate a bean. In request I also pass parameter id that identifies object in the session. Id parameter is not part of the bean. To populate id field in action prior to getModel() I used "params" interceptor in front of other interceptors. 
In Struts 2.3.15 I get lots of errors from ParametersInterceptor - no setter could be found. It throws errors for all fields that supposed to set my bean fields.
What is the right way to handle such situation?

Comment: Depends on a few factors. You have not provided enough code to be sure. Answers could range from custom interceptor, change existing interceptor configuration, or if you are doing this in just a couple places even using request aware and manually handing the id aspect in prepare() or even execute().

Comment: ParametersInterceptor before 2.3.15 had a bug - all those errors should be visible only in `devMode`, with 2.3.16 there be additional improvement in that area.

Comment: Here is my code:

<action name="testMD" class="com.TestMD">   
   <interceptor-ref name="params"/>  
   <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />  

Interceptor params used to populate id field. 
The method getModel() in action class returns object from the session based on id
It still works as expected in 2.3.15 but it logs errors as well.